# How do I prevent a single window from rotating when in a tabGroup?

Tags: android, ios, orientation, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a Titanium app with a tabGroup that has 4 tabs. I want to disable rotating and lockdown to whatever orientation the device is in when the second tab is active. The device can be free to rotate when any other tab is active. I've tried looking around, but haven't been able to come up with anything other than disabling orientation change completely.

I'd really appreciate any help in this matter!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

complete documentation on managining orientation change on Appcelerator

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Orientation

Comment: I'm not sure how this will work for windows within a tabGroup, but it's something I'll look into, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this but every tab contains an activity, so you can fix the orientation of that activity with `android:screenOrientation`. If what you want is to keep the first orientation your devices has when you press that tab, keep a static variable that you initialized in onCreateMethod.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a pretty good solution for android. However, I want this behavior to be there in iOS as well. Is there an equivalent for this on the iOS platform?